# Strange Behaviour While Finding Gender of Facebook users

Tags: php, facebook

When i Try to Retrieve Gender of a user..Its returning correct value.I use Below code for it

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
$user_gender = $user_profile['gender'];
echo "Gender: " . $user_gender;
```

But When I try to Retrieve Users Friends Gender with below code ,Its Returning 1

```
$user_ran= "100002944655532";
$user_gender = $user_ran['gender'];
echo "Gender: " . $user_gender;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call $facebook->api('/100002944655532','GET'); which will has "Female" as the gender value as seen [here](http://graph.facebook.com/100002944655532).